# Get predictions from clogitLasso() model?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, prediction

How would I get predictions from a `clogitLasso model`?

It will give me a sequence of penalty weights, and the covariate coefficients that go with them, but what I'd like to do next would be to choose one of those weights and predict using the associated model. Then I can evaluate the model using `AUC` or some such.

Open to suggestions using a different library, as well.

(Open to getting bounced to CrossValidated, as well, but this isn't really a theoretical question. . . .)

Comment: We need a reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Also, try the `glmnet` package.

Comment: @hmhensen -- `glmnet` doesn't have a provision for strata, which we need to code the case-control matched sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `predict()` function for `clogitLasso()`, but I was overthinking this. You can do the matrix multiplication of the data by the coefficients yourself.

For instance:

First we'll simulate some data. 360 observations, in 180 case/control pairs. `case` is coded 1/0, and `set` numbers the 180 pairs. There are two covariates: `e1` is noise, and `x1` is associated with the outcome, `case`.

```
library("clogitLasso")
set.seed(0)
N <- 360
mm <- data.frame(case=rep(c(1, 0), times=N/2))
mm$set <- rep(1:(N/2), each=2)
mm$e1 <- rnorm(n=N, mean=5, sd=10)
mm$x1 <- mm$case*10 + rnorm(n=N, mean=0, sd=3)
```

To get predictions from clogitLasso we need to normalize the covariates (mean = 0, sd = 1) ourselves, before putting the data into the model. (Otherwise clogitLasso translates the coefficients back to the "original scale", which is useless here.)

```
mm[, c("e1", "x1")] <- scale(mm[, c("e1", "x1")], center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
```

Then build the model:

```
model <- clogitLasso(X=as.matrix(mm[, c("e1", "x1")]), y=as.matrix(mm$case), 
    strata=mm$set, standardize=FALSE)
```

We need to choose which value of the penalty weight we want to test the predictions for -- here we'll choose the 10th, just because.

And we multiply the original input data by the coefficients ("betas") to attempt to predict the original outcomes -- the value of `case`:

```
handMadePredictions <- as.matrix(mm[, c("e1", "x1")]) %*% model$beta[10, ]
```

This is the linear predictor, which we need to transform back to the probability scale for prediction:

```
logistic <- function(logOdds) {
  return(exp(logOdds) / (exp(logOdds) + 1))
}

handMadePredictions <- logistic(handMadePredictions)
```

The original data -- `case` -- was a series of alternating ones and zeros. We can see that this model predicted those outcomes, from the original inputs, quite well. Either by inspecting `round(handMadePredictions)` or with a confusion matrix:

```
table("predicted"=round(handMadePredictions), "Case/control"=mm$case)

         Case/control
predicted   0   1
        0 172  12
        1   8 168
```

**Note** that in this toy example there are *no stratum effects* -- the association between `x1` and `case` is the same, no matter what `set` the datapoints are in. In this simplified situation there is no need for conditional logistic regression, regular logistic regression will work just fine. But I haven't been able to get plausible prediction results from `clogitLasso()` when there are stratum effects, which is a whole other question.